# Playing Sound Using the Android MediaPlayer in a switch statement

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to get my application to play sounds when the current exercise is shown on screen. The problem I'm having is that the sound keeps repeating once it is played. I want the media player to play the sound once. I have a count down timer running also and the exerciseCount is 0 for 15 seconds before changing. The sound keeps repeating on each number that the clock counts down. How to i get the sound to play only once?

```
        switch (currentExercise){
     case 0 :
          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.lunges); 
          mp.start();
      break;
     case 1 :
          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.abdominalcrunches);
          mp.start();
      break;
     case 2 :
          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.pushups);
          mp.start();
      break;
     case 3 :
          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.squats);
          mp.start();
      break;
     case 4 :
          mp.reset();
          mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.rest);
          mp.start();
      break;

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try putting an if statement surrounding your switch. Something like:

```
if(timer == -1){
     switch (currentExercise){
 case 0 :
      mp.reset();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.lunges); 
      mp.start();
  break;
 case 1 :
      mp.reset();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.abdominalcrunches);
      mp.start();
  break;
 case 2 :
      mp.reset();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.pushups);
      mp.start();
  break;
 case 3 :
      mp.reset();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.squats);
      mp.start();
  break;
 case 4 :
      mp.reset();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.rest);
      mp.start();
  break;

  }
  }
```

It may be that your switch is looping.